# 404 needed instead of Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: Permission denied in Unknown on line 0 on pages with XX0 permissions

Tags: php, apache, configuration, permissions, http-status-code-404

Using PHP Version 5.3.15 with Apache 2 on a Mac Web Server.

A while back (it's been years) I had this working right and I have no idea what has changed so I was wondering if anyone has a solution.

What I would like to happen is when a file with a "0" permission in the everyone slot (ie 770, 640, etc) is called by the browser from our server the user gets a 404 or page not found. Right now if a file with 0 for everyone is opened the following is displayed in the browser:

**Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: Permission denied in Unknown on line 0
Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required '/*path to site*/www/membership/donate_vehicle.php' (include_path='.:') in Unknown on line 0**

Example: http://wfsu.org/membership/donate_vehicle.php

Does anyone know how to make a 404 page there instead? It's got to be a configuration or something, because like I said, it was this way on our old server, which was an older Mac server running an older version of PHP and Apache, just not sure what.

Thanks

Comment: how is PHP set up ? As an apache Module or CGI ?

Comment: php5_module is activated in the server admin under "modules" so I would hopefully assume - module -  correctly

Comment: Apache is going to read that as a 200 response because it did load the page correctly.  You could change the permissions of Apache to not be allowed to open those files, but then you'd have a new error code like a 50X code.  I would recommend that you use a php redirect when it can't open a file.  Redirect to your own 404 page.

Answer (score 0):

```
$myfile = '/path/to/file.php';

if( file_exists($myfile) && is_readable($myfile) ) {
    require($myfile);
} else {
    // do 404 stuff
}
```